# read.index( ) appears to be reading the wrong index?

Tags: python

So I've spent a couple of days on this and I can't figure out the answer. But I've stripped the problem down to the simplest form (I think). I'm trying to find two different strings in a file, and read the section of the file between them. Right now I have a tester file with literally just 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, etc in it. I'm running this code:

```
with open('Testing.txt', 'r') as file:
   read = file.read()
   if "4" in read:
        begin = read.index("4")
        print begin
        if "8" in read:
            end = read.index("8")
            file.seek(begin)
            print "The location to begin reading is", file.tell()
            data= file.read()[begin:end]
            print "data =", data
```

If I start at 1, the code works properly. If I start somewhere above 2, it pulls numbers way farther down the list than it should. I'm sort of at a loss for why this is happening. I hope I'm making sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you make `file.seek(begin)`, `file.read()` will read the file from `begin` and not from the start of the file.

So either make `file.seek(0)` or change the way you calculate data: `data= file.read()[:end - begin]`

But why do you read your file a second time, you already have the file content in `read` variable. Just do:

```
data = read[begin:end]
```

Moreover:

- You could use a regular expression, or `split` function instead of calculating indexes.
- Avoid using `read` as a variable name, because it is confusing the reader who is used to using read on open files.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I was being dumb like that!